# What's happening on this answer?

Tags: support, edits

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70765295/how-to-merge-list-of-dictionaries-in-python-in-shortest-and-fastest-way-possible), OP [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70765295/how-to-merge-list-of-dictionaries-in-python-in-shortest-and-fastest-way-possible/70765326?noredirect=1#comment125158122_70780750) on an answer (not theirs) with "Just updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out." but the answer itself was shown to be edited by the answerer, not OP. And the edit history says the edit happened at 5:35, and their comment was posted at 5:36.

The phrasing seems to suggest that OP edited that answer, but the edit history doesn't show their name. Is it perhaps the case of suggested edit, and then further edited by the answerer, making only the answerer as the editor?

I found it unlikely that the approval by the answerer happens 1 minute before OP commented, unless there is some notification perhaps. Did OP get notification when their edit is approved, and then post it right after they saw the notification?

I'm just curious in how weird the edit history, time, and the comment is, and would like to know what happened. So my questions:

1. Does further editing a suggested edit remove the original suggestor from the edit history when it's approved?
2. Does an edit suggestor (with <2000 reputation) get a notification when the edit is approved or further edited?

Comment: But meta cannot do anything about it, nor can now anything more than you can. If you suspect sock-pupetry, raise a custom mod flag.

Comment: I'm just trying to confirm some possibilities first (e.g., whether we get notification, etc.) since accusing of sock-puppet seems to be quite a big action, so would like to be careful before doing that (mods are already handling heavy loads, I think?) But yes, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Again, not much meta can do. Investigating fishy or non-fishy user-activities is not a thing a crowd or mob is best suited for.

Comment: Well, if you noticed, I didn't mention any sock-puppetry at all in my question, and phrased it as carefully as possible to be as objective as possible, and least accusatory :) But I guess I should give more emphasis on the actual questions. Thanks for the feedback. I'm editing the question. I'm trying to gather the data. For example, you can help answering one of the questions: do editor get a notification when their edit is approved? Does further editing a suggested edit removes the suggestor name from the edit history?

Answer (score 43):

Seems like a case of *"Oops, wrong account."* The OP was in fact a sock puppet of the answerer. Thanks for bringing that to our attention.

Comment: _"Oops, wrong account"_ <-- this almost happened to me a couple of times (I obviously don't use my sock for vote fraud). I even wrote a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/9039/80115) specifically for this :-D.

Comment: Should the answer still be marked as the solution if it was a sock puppet? It looks like the user in question has still net gained that 15 reputation from their sock.

Comment: @Larnu Those votes should be invalidated by now.

Comment: @41686d6564 There was once a [feature-request] post titled *"Give users the option to disable interactions between accounts to get rid of the risk of accidental voting fraud"*, but the post got deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. For my actual question in the question body, does further editing a suggested edit overwrites the editor name in the edit history?

Comment: @just I believe so, yes. It’s basically two consecutive edits.

Comment: Oh, I meant, does the suggestor name not appear at all in the history, or does it appear? Two consecutive edits seem to suggest it should appear, but you answered "overwrites the editor name" with "yes".

Comment: @just Ah, it should not *replace* the name in the history, no. The latest visible name will be of the latest approver/editor, but the history will contain all.